# How to use date for x-Axis in SwiftChart?

Tags: swift, swiftcharts

I am trying to draw line chart in my project using SwiftChart pod. I am getting response from API as ["activity_count":0 , "date": "2020-10-31"] but graph works on double values so I don't know How I draw the chart.

```
import UIKit
import SwiftChart
class AnalyticsViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var graphContainer: UIView!
    var graphData = [(x:0, y: 0.0)]
    var graphpResponseData = [[String: Any]]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    graphpResponseData.append(["activity_count":0 , "date": "2020-10-31"])
    graphpResponseData.append(["activity_count":2 , "date": "2020-10-30"])
    graphpResponseData.append(["activity_count":1 , "date": "2020-10-29"])
    graphpResponseData.append(["activity_count":29 , "date": "2020-10-28"])
    graphpResponseData.append(["activity_count":1 , "date": "2020-10-27"])
    graphpResponseData.append(["activity_count":0 , "date": "2020-10-26"])
    graphpResponseData.append(["activity_count":0 , "date": "2020-10-25"])
    graphpResponseData.append(["activity_count":0 , "date": "2020-10-24"])
    graphpResponseData.append(["activity_count":0 , "date": "2020-10-23"])
    graphpResponseData.append(["activity_count":0 , "date": "2020-10-22"])
    
   ???? unable to proceed
    //let chart = Chart(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 100))
            //let series = ChartSeries(data: graphData)
    //chart.add(series)
    //chart.xLabels = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    //chart.xLabelsFormatter = { String(Int(round($1))) + "Oct" }
    //graphContainer.addSubview(chart)
}


}
```

desired output [image]

Answer (score 1):

I just had to solve this issue. I was using the day of the month of each date in memory for the x-axis, but it turned out that this would cause the graph to act unexpectedly and show randomly plotted points when the month changed.

I also tried using timestamps for x (of type `Double`, which would be accepted by the ChartSeries's data initializer, but this failed too.

The solution I found was to use an increment of one for each point on the x-axis, and using an array of `[Date]` whose indices corresponded with the order of the datapoints in your chart's `data` property (for the sake of example, call this `correspondingDates`). Inside of `chart.xLabelsFormatter`, I'd access this array using `correspondingDates[value]`. From there, I used two dateFormatter extensions to access the values.

Here's the code:

```
chart.xLabelsFormatter = { (index,value) in        
 //Format for label
 let date = correspondingDates[Int(value)]
 let dayAbbr = DateFormatter.getDay(date: date)
 let monthAbbr = DateFormatter.getMonth(date: date)
 return monthAbbr + "-" + dayAbbr
```

Extensions for DateFormatter:

```
extension DateFormatter{
  
  /// Used specifically to get the Month Abrreviation (ie Feb), but can be used for formatting in other ways.
  /// - Parameter format: Can be 'LLL' for the month abbreviated to 3 letters, or something like 'D/MM/Y'
  /// - Returns: Returns the String version of the date, with precision at any level
  static func getMonth(format:String = "LLL",date: Date = Date())->String{
      let formatter = DateFormatter()
      let today = date // formatter.da(from: Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: Date()))
  
      formatter.dateFormat = format
      let string = formatter.string(from: today)
      return string
  }
  
  
  /// Used specifically to get the Day Abrreviation (ie 05 or 27), but can be used for formatting in other ways.
  /// - Parameters:
  ///   - format: Can be 'LLL' for the month abbreviated to 3 letters, or something like 'D/MM/Y'
  ///   - date: optionally pass in your own date
  /// - Returns:  Returns the String version of the day, with precision at any level
  static func getDay(format:String = "dd",date: Date = Date())->String{
      let formatter = DateFormatter()
      let today = date // formatter.da(from: Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: Date()))
  
      formatter.dateFormat = format
      let string = formatter.string(from: today)
      return string
  }
  
}
```